# How should I share a list of functions between the process and multiple DLLs loaded dynamically?

Tags: c++, dll, plugins

We have an embedded application in Windows CE 6.0 coded in C++ (custom SDK with custom hardware, Visual Studio 2008, winapi application) that loads dll dynamically and uses them like a plugin. This way of working helps our company sell features separately depending on the needs of the clients.

Some programmers want that two plugins be able to communicate between each other without calling functions of the executable. So it will let them add a new feature without forcing me to always compile a new version of the main application.

The way I thought is, each DLL gives to the process a list of functions they want to share. Then the process will give this list to all the dlls. The issue I have is that each function has a different declaration. I thought an array of void pointers would suit the situation and each dll would share a header containing typedef of functions. But I know that using a void pointer is a bad practice and it means that my design lacks thinking.

But when I'm trying to think about it I'm not able to find a better way. What is the best way to do that by having different functions without using void pointer of functions.

Here a simple example of my thinking

```
// Interface_Of_Shared_functions.h------------------------------    
typedef int (*function1)(int, int, int);
// -----------------------------------------




// ----------- plugin1 (dll 1)----------------
// function that the dll wants to share
int func(int param1, int param2, int param3);

typedef struct item_fct{
    std::string name;
    void* func_ptr;
}fct;

//share function called by the exe
void give_me_your_functions(std::vector<item_fct>& list)
{
    item_fct f;
    f.name = "func";
    f.function = &func;

    list.push_back(f);
}
//------------------------------------------



// --------------- plugin2 (dll 2) -----------
int calling_another_plugin_function()
{
     for(size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
     {
         if(list[i].name == "func")
         {
             function1 caller;
             caller = reinterpret_cast<function1>(list[i])
             int result_i_want = caller(1, 2, 3);
         }
     }
}
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an fixed list of function declarations you can use unions.

Inside main program

```
typedef struct item_fct{
    char* funcname;
    int funcID;
    int moduleID;
    void* funcnull;
} item_fct;
```

Inside DLLs

```
// ----------- plugins (dll)----------------
// function that the dll wants to share
typedef int (*funcintrf1) (int, int);
typedef int (*funcintrf2) (int, int, int);
typedef char (*funcintrf3) (int, int, double);
typedef double (*funcintrf4) (int, int, void*);

const int FUNC1_ID = 0x000101; 
const int FUNC2_ID = 0x000201; 
const int FUNC3_ID = 0x000301; 
const int FUNC4_ID = 0x000401; 

//synonyms
typedef struct funcdecl1 {
    int p1;
    int p2;
}

typedef struct funcdecl2 {
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int p3;
}

typedef struct funcdecl3 {
    int p1;
    int p2;
    double p3;
}

typedef struct funcdecl4 {
    int p1;
    int p2;
    void* p3;
}

typedef struct item_fct{
    char* funcname;
    int funcID;
    int moduleID;
    union {
        funcintrf1 func1;
        funcintrf2 func2;
        funcintrf3 func3;
        funcintrf4 func4;
        void* funcnull;
    };
} item_fct;

int calling_another_plugin_function(void* result, int amoduleID, int afuncID, void* aparams)
{
     item_fct* fct;
     for(size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
     {              
         if(list[i].funcID == afuncID && list[i].moduleID == amoduleID)
         {
             fct = list[i];
         }
     }
     if (amoduleID == 1) {
         switch (afuncID) {
            case FUNC1_ID : {
               funcdecl1 * p = (funcdecl1*)aparams;
               *((int*)result) = (*fct).func1((*p).p1, (*p).p2);
               break;
            }
            case FUNC2_ID : {
               funcdecl2 * p = (funcdecl2*)aparams;
               *((int*)result) = (*fct).func2((*p).p1, (*p).p2, (*p).p3);
               break;
            }
            case FUNC3_ID : {
               funcdecl3 * p = (funcdecl3*)aparams;
               *((char*)result) = (*fct).func3((*p).p1, (*p).p2, (*p).p3);
               break;
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not what I'm searching for. I don't know how this implementation will give flexibility to my plugins. You should read my question properly. Furthermore, this kind of implementation force the application and dlls to be recompiled if the structure change (so if someone add a new function somewhere in a plugin) and it's not what I'm looking for. I think it's worse than what I suggest. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you realy have an undefined declaration of functions? I think you should look to script languages or write your own simple one that can parse function from string